# What is the easy way to find all stored procedures, which are used in some specific asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to find all SPs, which are used in particular page. Problem, that they aren't called directly from page, but from other assemblies in other projects. So, I need to analyse all code to find them. I just think maybe some other method exists? Just run this page in application and catch all moments when SQL server is calling? Using VS 2010, MSSQL 2008, C#, web forms.

Comment: If you are the only person using that page at the time, you could run a trace on the SQL server, targeting only that database to see what procedures get called.

Comment: You could turn on SQL profiler to see activity but that won't guarantee you'd find them ALL, depending on your logic

Comment: I run profiler, but too many processes running on the server, it's difficult to see call from this page. Trace, it's what you create in profiler, right? Maybe you can it shows only calls from this application?

Comment: and it shows events on all DBs on server, how I can choose only one? okay, found filters.

Comment: Btw, I wonder if there is some option or filter to show every SP only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the idea about using Profiler to get list of SPs on some specific pages in application, which I develop from two people, who left comments. Here I just wabt to share details how I used Profiler:

1. Run Profiler
2. Choose TSQ_SPs Template
3. On the Event Selection tab select "Show all columns" checkbox
4. On the same page check only one event: SP:Completed
5. On Colum Filters set filters for ApplicationName, DatabaseName, HostName, LoginName.
   Actually it's enough only DatabaseName and HostName. HostName as my computer name, because I run application locally from VS.
6. Save Trace properties as Template.
7. Run trace
8. Run application.
9. Before loading required page clean trace
10. Open page and pressing different buttons and controls on the page
11. After you finished with all actions on the page, save Trace as Trace Table to db.
12. Running the following query:

    SELECT DISTINCT ObjectName FROM SPTableName

and getting list of SPs for this page.
DISTINCT allows you to eliminate repeating SPs, because on each page SPs run many times.

Repeat 9 - 12 for each page.

Comment: This depends on the user running a scenario (in step 8) that uses all the SPs in the code, correct?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you mean. SPs called from page, but not directly, using other projects and libraries.

Comment: Let's say *all* the code in the page ultimately ends up with three SPs. Two of them are for functions used frequently, while the third is less frequent. The scenario used in step 8 has to include running all functionality of the page, including the lesser used one. Correct?

Comment: Yes, ideally you should use all functionality. So, for example, page for entering some info. You need to play with each dropdown, then save info several times with different options. But of course, it doesn't give you 100% that you get all SPs. So you need analyse code anyway. But because on every page about 50-100 SPs is calling, running Profiler first and create draft list of SPs can save you lot of time.